# Convert string to double variable which is seperated by a comma(0,07)

Tags: c++, double

In C++ I've got a double variable to be read which is seperated by a comma(0,07).I am first reading it a string from an excel and trying to converting it into a double.

```
string str = "0,07"; // Actually from Excel.
double number = strtod(str .c_str(), NULL);
double number1 = atof(str .c_str());
cout << number<<endl;
cout <<number1<<endl;
```

Both of them return 0 as output instead of 0.07. can someone explain me how to convert double to 0.07 instead of 0.

Comment: If you use an appropriate locale, a string stream should parse it properly.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale

Comment: In reality, ignore locales. The problem is that your input will rarely be sanitized enough for them to work. If you _know_ that your input shouldn't contain comma's, just replace `','` by `'.'` outright. This continues to work even if the input has a mix of comma's and dots.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: did you try it? I could not make it work for parsing a string...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a customized numeric facet ([numpunct](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct)) for it:

```
class My_punct : public std::numpunct<char> {
protected:
    char do_decimal_point() const {return ',';}//comma
};
```

and then use a [stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) and [locale](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale) with it:

```
stringstream ss("0,07");
locale loc(locale(), new My_punct);
ss.imbue(loc);
double d;
ss >> d;
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/olqnh9)

Comment: See also: `std::numpunct_byname`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the default locale is the "C" (for "Classic"), that uses '.' as decimal separator, while excel use the one of the OS. that is most likely the one of a lain language.

You can either:

- ask the originator of the data to export with an english-like locale
- set in your program a locale based on `std::locale("")`(so that your program work with the system locale -admitting they are the same, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale)
- set you program with a latin-based locale (IT, or ES, for example)
- ignore locales and replace the ","-s in the string with "."-s before try to interpret it as number. (see [std::replace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace))

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), ',', '.'); // #include <algorithm>
```

to replace the comma by a dot before converting.

Working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "0,07"; // Actually from Excel.
    replace(str.begin(), str.end(), ',', '.');

    double number = strtod(str.c_str(), NULL);
    double number1 = atof(str.c_str());
    cout << number << endl;
    cout << number1 << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Would this be fine ?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     string str = "0,07"; // Actually from Excel.
     int index = str.find(',');
     str.replace(index, index+1, '.');

     double number = stod(str);

     cout << number << endl;

     return 0;
}
```

PS: `stod` is a `c++11` function, but you need to use it instead of `stof` if you want to keep the double precision. Otherwise `number` should be a `float`