# How to cast string with comma to double using boost

Tags: c++, boost, casting

it is possible to do something like that

```
std::string str = "127,8";
double x = boost::lexical_cast<double>(str);
```

I tried it but it throws an exception, do u have a simple way to do such cast using boost ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string to double variable which is seperated by a comma(0,07)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32013041/convert-string-to-double-variable-which-is-seperated-by-a-comma0-07)

Comment: For me it works for "127.8" and not for "127,8" but I know others use `,` instead of `.` for the decimal point: [http://cpp.sh/8dwdqe](http://cpp.sh/8dwdqe)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom locale that uses `,` for the decimal point. Code taken and modified from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7277333/4117728

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
class comma_numpunct : public std::numpunct<char>
{
  protected:
    virtual char do_decimal_point() const
    {
        return ',';
    }


};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::string str = "127,8";
    std::locale comma_locale(std::locale(), new comma_numpunct());
    std::locale::global(comma_locale);
    double x = boost::lexical_cast<double>(str);
}
```

Comment: you don't need a custom locale, most European locales use `,` for the radix point

Comment: For OP: you can use `std::numpunct_byname<char>("fr_FR.UTF8")` or any other locale having a comma as a decimal separator (Used OP's location, as defined in their profile).